# I received error Code 1054 unknown column "Charadrius_vociferus" in 'field list'

Tags: sql, syntax-error

```
CREATE TABLE birds (
bird_id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
Scientific_name varchar(255) unique,
Common_name Varchar(80), Family_id INT, description text) ;

Describe Birds;

INSERT INTO birds (scientific_name, common_name)
VALUES (‘Charadrius_vociferus’, ‘Killdeer’),
       (‘Gavia_immer’, ‘Great_Northern_Loon’),
       (‘Aix_sponsa’, ‘Wood_Duck’),
       (‘Chordeiles_minor’, ‘Common_Nighthawk’),
       (‘Sitta_carolinensis’, ‘White-breasted_Nuthatch’),
       (‘Apteryx_mantelli’, ‘North_Island_Brown_Kiwi’);
```

I have followed the instructions on syntax to a T on the tutorial. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: can it be the strange quotes around strings ? looks like you copy/pasted something from a word document (word has this awful auto-correct that replaces quotes)

Comment: Use proper quote (`'`), not some fancy quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO birds (scientific_name, common_name)
VALUES ('Charadrius_vociferus', 'Killdeer'),
       ('Gavia_immer', 'Great_Northern_Loon'),
       ('Aix_sponsa', 'Wood_Duck'),
       ('Chordeiles_minor', 'Common_Nighthawk'),
       ('Sitta_carolinensis', 'White-breasted_Nuthatch'),
       ('Apteryx_mantelli', 'North_Island_Brown_Kiwi');
```

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: "didn't work" will not help us help you.  Didn't work how?  Nothing inserted?  Error out?  If error out, what's the error?